# Load Json Script with Flask Request, convert to pandas Dataframe and back to Json as Flask Response

Tags: python, json, flask, request, pandasql

I am using Python/pickle for my scoring model. The data to be scored will come from a Flask Request as a Json Script. Need to read the data from a Flask Request, convert data to a pandas dataframe, transform the data via pandasql, call on the scoring model and output the scoring results dataframe as a Flask Response in Json.

1. I can get everything above to work when the incoming data is a Json file on my hard drive (using json.load()).
2. For debugging, i can use a Flask request to load the Json script as well as convert it to a dataframe and return the dataframe as a Flask Response in Json.
3. **HOWEVER,** after loading the Json script via Flask Request, i attempt to use **pandasql** to transform the data but get the Error the dataframe is not found "Exception: df not found".

   - How can i solve this issue? Thank you in advance (code and Json script below)

Per #2 above: this code works.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def load():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
    df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])

    resp = make_response(df.to_json())
    return resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Per Issue #3: This code does not work! Using pandasql to transform dataframe gets the Error: 'df is not found' (full traceback at bottom)**

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/results', methods=['POST'])
def load():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
    df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])

# set up query to transform data (simple example)
    q = """ 
        Select *
        from df 
        """
    query = pandasql.sqldf(q, globals())

    resp = make_response(query.to_json())
    resp.mimetype = 'application/json'
    return resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Full Error traceback:

```
File "C:\ app.py", line 1836, in __call__
  return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
line 1820, in wsgi_app
  response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
line 1403, in handle_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
line 1817, in wsgi_app
  response = self.full_dispatch_request()
line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
line 1381, in handle_user_exception
  reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
  rv = self.dispatch_request()
line 1461, in dispatch_request
  return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
line 52, in load
  query = pandasql.sqldf(q, globals())
line 108, in sqldf
  raise Exception("%s not found" % table)
Exception: df not found
```

Json Script:

```
{
    "response":{
      "version":"1.1",
      "token":"dsfgf",
       "body":{
         "customer":{
             "customer_id":"1234567",
             "verified":"true"
        },
         "contact":{
             "email":"mr@abc.com",
             "mobile_number":"0123456789"
        },
         "personal":{
             "gender": "m",
             "title":"Dr.",
             "last_name":"Muster",
             "first_name":"Max",
             "family_status":"single",
             "dob":"1985-12-23"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

- replace globals() with locals() within [ query = pandasql.sqldf(q, globals()) ]

For more complex needs with multiple dataframes to Join see comments at https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/issues/42